# What is the maximum number of nested records in a record?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I create a record in BigQuery how many different nested records can I have inside in the schema? Is there a limit to the size of the schema?
Is this possible:
AA: Record
  A1: Record
  A2: Record
  ....
  A1000: Record

Note, I understand there is an option to have A be a repeated record, I am not interested\not asking about this option.

Thanks

Comment: I read that the total number of columns per table is 10000. If I have nested records, is the maximum number of columns in the entire record 10000? Or can I have multiple nested records\nodes each of which can have 10000 columns and the node\record counts as 1 column?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum schema nesting depth allowed is 100.
That is, you can have a record that looks like
{a1: {a2: {a3: { a4: {... {a100: "foo" } ...}}}

Comment: Also note that currently, the maximum size of an entire BigQuery record is 64KB. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#jsonformat

Comment: @MichaelManoochehri there is no mention about the limit you described at the docs page you linked.

Comment: Looks like the docs have changed since I posted that comment 4 years ago! I cannot find an update here, can you?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy

Answer (score 0):

This limit @2020 stands at 150

> BigQuery supports columns of type STRUCT (or RECORD). A STRUCT is a complex type that can be used to represent an object that has multiple child columns. In a STRUCT column, you can also define one or more of the child columns as STRUCT types (referred to as nested or embedded STRUCTs). When you nest STRUCTS, BigQuery enforces a nested depth limit of 15 levels. The nested depth limit is independent of whether the STRUCTs are scalar or array-based.

Refer the complete documentation - [BQ nested and repeated columns limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#limitations)